# Google IO Tango Unity example not working

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm having alot of trouble with the Google IO codelab for Tango https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/project-tango#1

After I finished it, it runs but it only turns, it doesnt move forward and backwars like the other tango apps in the play store.

I started on this yesterday but even after two days of debugging, I cannot get it to work right. Today I got so frustrated that I deleted everything and started over from scratch and it is still broken. I can get the permissions so I think tango is up and running, but not moving. I have enabled motion tracking and disabled/removed the scripts and code as specified in the tutorial. My PoseController looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Tango;
using System;

public class PoseController : MonoBehaviour , ITangoPose {
private TangoApplication m_tangoApplication; // Instance for Tango Client
private Vector3 m_tangoPosition; // Position from Pose Callback
private Quaternion m_tangoRotation; // Rotation from Pose Callback
private Vector3 m_startPosition; // Start Position of the camera
private Vector3 m_lastPosition; // last position returned in Unity coordinates.

// Controls movement scale, use 1.0f to be metric accurate
// For the codelab, we adjust the scale so movement results in larger movements in the
// virtual world.
private float m_movementScale = 10.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    // Initialize some variables
    m_tangoRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    m_tangoPosition = Vector3.zero;
    m_lastPosition = Vector3.zero;
    m_startPosition = transform.position;
    m_tangoApplication = FindObjectOfType<TangoApplication>();
    if(m_tangoApplication != null)
    {
        RequestPermissions();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No Tango Manager found in scene.");
    }
}

// Permissions callback
private void PermissionsCallback(bool success)
{
    if(success)
    {
        m_tangoApplication.InitApplication(); // Initialize Tango Client
        m_tangoApplication.InitProviders(string.Empty); // Initialize listeners
        m_tangoApplication.ConnectToService(); // Connect to Tango Service
    }
    else
    {
        AndroidHelper.ShowAndroidToastMessage("Motion Tracking Permissions Needed", true);
    }

}

private void RequestPermissions()
{
    // Request Tango permissions
    m_tangoApplication.RegisterPermissionsCallback(PermissionsCallback);
    m_tangoApplication.RequestNecessaryPermissionsAndConnect();
    m_tangoApplication.Register(this);
}

// Pose callbacks from Project Tango
public void OnTangoPoseAvailable(Tango.TangoPoseData pose)
{


    // Do nothing if we don't get a pose
    if (pose == null) {
        Debug.Log("TangoPoseData is null.");
        return;
    }
    // The callback pose is for device with respect to start of service pose.
    if (pose.framePair.baseFrame == TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE &&
        pose.framePair.targetFrame == TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE)
    {
        if (pose.status_code == TangoEnums.TangoPoseStatusType.TANGO_POSE_VALID)
        {
            // Cache the position and rotation to be set in the update function.
            m_tangoPosition = new Vector3((float)pose.translation [0],
                                          (float)pose.translation [1],
                                          (float)pose.translation [2]);

            m_tangoRotation = new Quaternion((float)pose.orientation [0],
                                             (float)pose.orientation [1],
                                             (float)pose.orientation [2],
                                             (float)pose.orientation [3]);
        }
        else // if the current pose is not valid we set the pose to identity
        {
            m_tangoPosition = Vector3.zero;
            m_tangoRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Transforms the Tango pose which is in Start of Service to Device frame to Unity coordinate system.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The Tango Pose in unity coordinate system.</returns>
/// <param name="translation">Translation.</param>
/// <param name="rotation">Rotation.</param>
/// <param name="scale">Scale.</param>
Matrix4x4 TransformTangoPoseToUnityCoordinateSystem(Vector3 translation,
                                                    Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
{

    // Matrix for Tango coordinate frame to Unity coordinate frame conversion.
    // Start of service frame with respect to Unity world frame.
    Matrix4x4 m_uwTss;
    // Unity camera frame with respect to device frame.
    Matrix4x4 m_dTuc;

    m_uwTss = new Matrix4x4();
    m_uwTss.SetColumn (0, new Vector4 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_uwTss.SetColumn (1, new Vector4 (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_uwTss.SetColumn (2, new Vector4 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_uwTss.SetColumn (3, new Vector4 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    m_dTuc = new Matrix4x4();
    m_dTuc.SetColumn (0, new Vector4 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_dTuc.SetColumn (1, new Vector4 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_dTuc.SetColumn (2, new Vector4 (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_dTuc.SetColumn (3, new Vector4 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    Matrix4x4 ssTd = Matrix4x4.TRS(translation, rotation, scale);
    return m_uwTss * ssTd * m_dTuc;
}


// FixedUpdate is called at a fixed rate
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Convert position and rotation from Tango's coordinate system to Unity's.
    Matrix4x4 uwTuc = TransformTangoPoseToUnityCoordinateSystem(m_tangoPosition,
                                                                m_tangoRotation, Vector3.one);
    Vector3 newPosition = (uwTuc.GetColumn(3))* m_movementScale;
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(uwTuc.GetColumn(2),
                                                     uwTuc.GetColumn(1));

    // Calculate the difference in the poses received.  This allows us
    // to recover when we hit something in the virtual world.
    Vector3 delta = newPosition - m_lastPosition;
    m_lastPosition = newPosition;
    Vector3 destination = rigidbody.position + delta;
    Vector3 vectorToTargetPosition = destination - transform.position;
    // If there is motion, move the player around the scene.
    if(vectorToTargetPosition.magnitude > 0.1f)
    {
        vectorToTargetPosition.Normalize();
        // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
        Vector3 movement = vectorToTargetPosition;
        // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
        movement = movement.normalized * 5f * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
        rigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }
    else {
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
    // always rotate, even if we don't move.
    rigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
    // finally, let the game manager know the position of the player.
    GameManager.Instance.PlayerPosition = transform.position;
}
```

}

That was just a copy and paste of what was in the codelab, so at this point there is none of my own code and still I cannot run this correctly. What am I doing wrong????

I've done some android development before tango but I'm fairly new to unity. However, I've double and triple checked everything and also my device says everything is up to date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see enough to give an answer - but I can give a hint -  pose information returned from Tango contains both position and attitude -  if your rotations correspond with how you manipulate Tango, then the problem lies between collecting the pose and setting the camera position - I'd suggest stepping through it (have patience, debugging Tango with Unity necessitates flowing all the debug data over the wire)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the codelab has been updated and the last line in FixedUpdate was commented out "//GameManager.Instance.PlayerPosition = transform.position;".

https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/project-tango#7

Hope that helps.